# Python Dataframe - Create a new column with value based on length of existing column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe as follows.

```
d = {'ID' : ['123456789012345678', '3456789012345678']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

with output as

```
    ID
0   123456789012345678
1   3456789012345678
```

I would like to create a new column `is_valid` such that if the length of `ID value` is `18` then `true` else `false`
that is, the expected output is

```
            ID          is_valid
0   123456789012345678  Yes
1   3456789012345678    No
```

Now I am using regular expression as follows

```
expr = '^[0-9]{18}$'
df['is_valid'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.match(expr), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Is there any better way to achieve it ?

Comment: Is your ID always numbers? Or can there be alphabetic letters as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df['is_valid'] = df.ID.str.len().eq(18)
```

[out]

```
                   ID  is_valid
0  123456789012345678      True
1    3456789012345678     False
```

Answer (score 2):

## Your code :

```
 %timeit -n 1000
 expr = '^[0-9]{18}$'
 %timeit df['is_valid'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.match(expr), 'Yes', 'No')

#320 µs ± 7.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

## Other alternative:

```
%timeit -n 5000
%timeit df['validation']=['True' if len(s)>=18 else 'False' for s in df['ID']]

#201 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to switch between `Yes` and `No` based on condition:

```
df['is_valid'] = np.where(df.ID.str.len().eq(18), 'Yes', 'No')
#                   ID is_valid
#0  123456789012345678      Yes
#1    3456789012345678       No
```